# How to set pdo driver in apache?

Tags: php, debian, apache2

I have a Debian 11 server

On my website I have the following error:

```
Caused by: PDOException
could not find driver
```

According to what the `phpinfo()` function returns, my **php.ini** file is in:

`/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`

I have the following modules:

```
root@xxx:/var/www/html/xxx # php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
PDO
pdo_mysql
...
```

I have tried to uncomment the lines in the `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` file:
`extension = mysqli`
and
`extension = pdo_mysql`
and then do `service apache2 restart` but it doesn't work

How can I load the driver?

Comment: If the wanted module is loaded but you still have an error, it's probably more something wrong in your code than a server configuration issue. Does it work elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is working on another server.
The specific error occurs in `/var/www/html/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php at line 723`

The vendor folder is generated by `composer update`, it is not code developed by us. There are libraries and dependencies

Comment: If I run `phpinfo()` on my website it says that I have php 7.4.26. However if I run on the server `php -v` I have 8.0.13 version.
Could the command `php -m` be confusing me? Is the module actually loaded?

Comment: Yes, it's possible the CLI version you are running is not the same as the apache version. In the phpinfo() the interesting part is the `PDO drivers` enabled in the `PDO` section.